# Where is the error ValueError: ModelForm has no model class specified

Tags: django-models, django-forms

I can't fix the problem. I want to generate weeks and give it a name but it returns an error --> ValueError: ModelForm has no model class specified.

Django version 2.2.24
Python3

CODE:

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Semana(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lunes_inicio = models.TimeField()
    lunes_fin = models.TimeField()
    martes_inicio = models.TimeField()
    martes_fin = models.TimeField()
    miercoles_inicio = models.TimeField()
    miercoles_fin = models.TimeField()
    jueves_inicio = models.TimeField()
    jueves_fin = models.TimeField()
    viernes_inicio = models.TimeField()
    viernes_fin = models.TimeField()
    sabado_inicio = models.TimeField()
    sabado_fin = models.TimeField()
    domingo_inicio = models.TimeField()
    domingo_fin = models.TimeField()
```

`forms.py`

```
from django import forms
from TaskManager.models import Semana

class FormularioSemana(forms.ModelForm):
    class meta:
        model = Semana
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {'lunes_inicio': forms.TimeInput(attrs={'type': 'time'})}
```

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpRequest

from .models import Semana
from .forms import FormularioSemana

def task(request):

     return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")


class FormularioSemanaView(HttpRequest):

    def index(request):
        semana = FormularioSemana()
        return render(request, "semana.html", {"form":semana})
    
    def procesar(request):
        semana = FormularioSemana(request.post)
        if semana.is_valid():
            semana.save()
            semana = FormularioSemana()
        return render(request, "semana.html", {"form":semana, "mensaje": OK})
```

`urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import FormularioSemanaView


urlpatterns = [

    path('task/', views.task, name='task' ),
    path('semana/', FormularioSemanaView.index, name='semana'),
    path('guardarSemana/', FormularioSemanaView.procesar, name='guardarSemana')
]
```

I'm starting to despair
I tried with several columns with attrs time and only one how this example, left only two columns,

Comment: Use `Meta` instead of `meta`. The case matters

Comment: It seems the correct fix, thanksss!!!!!